# How to have 3 calls of fork() and create 6 processes without using a loop

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I was given the task of creating exactly 6 processes using the c language and the command fork() and then have all 6 sleep using sleep() for a minute or two. The tougher part with this is that we are not allowed to use any loops at all, and only 3 calls to fork() total.
I have managed to create 8 successfully but that is too many. So I was wondering if it is possible to fork or kill specific processes.I tried something I saw here but it is giving me 8 process not 6

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{

/* fork a child process */
pid_t child = fork();
pid_t parent = getpid();


 fork(); //2
 if (fork() > 0) {//now we have 2 processes
     //only the parent calls this fork because of the if, so we have 3 processes
    fork(); //all 3 processes calls this fork, so we have 6 processes
    wait(NULL);
    printf("I am the child process");
    printf("my PID = %d ",child);
    printf("I am the parent process. My PID is %d\n", parent);

     wait(NULL);
    
}
    else if (child < 0) { /* error occurred */
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
    return 1;
}


}
```

out I am getting is:

```
I am the child processmy PID = 22150 I am the parent process. My PID is 22149
I am the child processmy PID = 22150 I am the parent process. My PID is 22149
I am the child processmy PID = 0 I am the parent process. My PID is 22150
I am the child processmy PID = 22150 I am the parent process. My PID is 22149
I am the child processmy PID = 0 I am the parent process. My PID is 22150
I am the child processmy PID = 0 I am the parent process. My PID is 22150
I am the child processmy PID = 0 I am the parent process. My PID is 22150
I am the child processmy PID = 22150 I am the parent process. My PID is 22149
```

Comment: The return value of `fork()` tells you whether you are in the parent or child process, and (in the parent only) whether forking was successful.  Read its documentation for details.  You can use that to discriminate among the processes to choose which ones should fork further.

Comment: You are calling `fork` 4 times.  Perhaps you did not intent to call `fork` when you initialized the variable `child`.  If you remove that call, your logic seems to be correct and you get 6 processes, as desired.

Comment: But note the ambiguity in the phrase "calling fork 4 times".  In your code there are 4 different instances of the token "fork", but it is called 11 times in total.

Comment: Although your program is giving you 8 lines of ouptut, you have 12 processes.  Not all of them are producing output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a tree with 6 new processes (+1 the orginal) by making the third fork only in 3 out of the fourth processes
that you'll have after the 1st 2 forks.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*
Process tree:
  /
 /\
/\/
  \

\  /
  /\
  \
*/

int main()
{
    _Bool descended_from_parent, descended_from_child;
    pid_t pid;
    if(0>(pid=fork())) return perror("fork"),1;
    descended_from_parent = pid == 0;
    if(0>(pid=fork())) return perror("fork"),1;
    descended_from_child = pid == 0;
    if(!descended_from_parent || descended_from_child) if(0>(pid=fork())) return perror("fork"),1;
    sleep(60);
}
// run as `./a.out &` and then do `ps --forest` to see the process tree
```

Comment: @bruno Must have misunderstood it then. Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int f1 = -1, f2 = -1, f3 = -1;
    printf("1 process running -- f1: %d; f2: %d; f3: %d\n", f1, f2, f3);

    sleep(1); // try to prevent print lines mangling
    f1 = fork(); // assume it worked
    printf("2 processes running -- f1: %d; f2: %d; f3: %d\n", f1, f2, f3);

    sleep(1); // try to prevent print lines mangling
    f2 = fork(); // assume it worked for the 2 running processes
    printf("4 processes running -- f1: %d; f2: %d; f3: %d\n", f1, f2, f3);

    sleep(1); // try to prevent print lines mangling
    if ((f1 > 0) || (f2 > 0)) f3 = fork(); // assume it worked for the 3 selected processes
    printf("7 processes running -- f1: %d; f2: %d; f3: %d\n", f1, f2, f3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `printf` followed by `fork` without an inervening `fflush` and expect reasonable output.  You should not rely on stdout being line buffered.  (Execute this with a regular file for stdout and you will see very different output than when stdout is a tty.)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is just fine.  I suspect the confusion is because of the initialization of the variable `child`, in which you invoke `fork` for the first time.  Also, your output is odd, and you are not reporting output for each process.  Simply refactoring your code to something simpler shows that your logic is correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>    
int
main(void)
{
        fork();
        if( fork() == 0 ) {
                fork();
        }
        printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
}
```

The above is basically your code, and it gives exactly 6 lines of output, as desired. The only real difference is that I removed the spurious initial call to `fork`, and moved the printf to the right place.  In your code, you have 4 processes when your comment claims there are only 2 (because of the spurious initialization fork), and all 4 of them fork again to make 8.  Of those 8, 4 of them refork to give you a total of 12, of which only 8 print any output. (The 4 that forked and their new children.)  The output that they give is most unusual, though, and does not reflect the actual pid of the process writing the output.  They merely show the pids as the were after the initial fork in the initialization of `child`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    fork() && fork();
    fork();
    printf("%d %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. In particular, what is the benefit of `fork() && fork();` over two `fork();` statements?